# Can a server force expiration of another HTTP resource?

Tags: http, caching, browser-cache, cache-control, expires-header

Let's say we have an HTTP server that handles two URLs: `http://server/foo` and `http://server/bar`. And let's say we have only one HTTP agent ever hitting those URLs.

The server will add distant-future cache headers on requests to `/foo` because, most of the time, this resource will be the same for the foreseeable future and it would make sense for agents to cache it.

Well, it's actually really the same until the agent hits `/bar`. At this point the `/foo` resource should be re-fetched because the cached version is most likely not up-to-date.

So can the server, when handling a request for `/bar`, also indicate the HTTP agent that any cached version of `/foo` should be discarded and re-fetched if needed?